# How to return a list of all neighbors for all triangles from Octave's delaunay() function?

Tags: octave, delaunay

I like Octave's "T = delaunay( p )" for constructing triangular meshes from a given set of points "p," but I am confused on how to call all neighbors for a specified triangle list "T." The example Octave code below uses a crude function I wrote that computes all neighbors in a O(n^2) number of steps.

```
octave:15> [(1:size(T,1))' T neighbors ]
ans =

   1   3   2   1   0   4   2
   2   5   3   2   1   3   5
   3   5   4   2   0   2   6
   4   7   3   1   1   0   5
   5   5   7   3   4   2   7
   6   6   5   4   3   8   7
   7   6   5   7   5   9   6
   8   6   4   8   0   9   6
   9   6   7   8   0   8   7
```

The first column contains the numerically ordered triangles. The second through fourth columns are the numerically labeled points contained by the triangles computed from T = delaunay(p). The fifth through seventh columns are the numerically labeled triangles who are neighbors to the specified ordered triangles.

Could someone provide sample Octave code that computes the neighbors for all triangles? Thanks.